# Mongoose showing error : "ValidationError: Product validation failed: name: Cast to string failed for....."

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, validationerror

I have a code where a schema for storing information about product has been defined followed by the code to add product information. Here is the code:

```
const Product=mongoose.model("Product", {
    id:{
        type: Number, 
        required: true,
    },
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    image:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    new_price:{
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    old_price:{
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
    available:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    },
})

app.post('/addproduct', async (req, res)=>{
    let products = await Product.find({});
    let id;
    if (products.length>0){
        let last_product_array = products.slice(-1);
        let last_product = last_product_array[0];
        id = last_product.id+1;
    }
    else{
        id=1;
    }
    const product = new Product({
        id: id,
        name: req.body.name,
        image: req.body.image,
        category: req.body.category,
        new_price: req.body.new_price,
        old_price: req.body.old_price,
    });
    console.log(product);
    await product.save();
    console.log("Saved");
    res.json({
        success: true,
        name: req.body.name,
    })
})
```

Here is the code from front-end where I am making the request:

```
    const AddProduct = () => {

  const [image, setImage] = useState(false);
  const [productDetails, setProductDetails] = useState({
    name:"",
    image: "",
    category: "women",
    new_price:"",
    old_price: ""
  })

  const imageHandler = (e)=>{
     setImage(e.target.files[0]);

  }
  const changeHandler = (e) =>{
    setProductDetails({...productDetails, [e.target.name]:[e.target.value]})
  }

  const Add_Product = async () =>{
        console.log(productDetails)
        
        let responseData;
        let product = productDetails;

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('product', image);
        await fetch('http://localhost:4000/upload',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
            body: formData,
        }).then((resp)=>resp.json()).then((data)=>{responseData=data});
        if (responseData.success)
        {
            product.image=responseData.image_url;
            console.log(product);
            
            await fetch('http://localhost:4000/addproduct', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers:{
                    Accept:'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(product),
            }).then((resp)=>resp.json()).then((data)=>{
                data.success?alert("Product added"):alert("Failed")
            })
        }
        
  }

  return (
    <div className='add-product'>
        <div className='addproduct-itemfield'>
            <p>Product title</p>
            <input value={productDetails.name} onChange={changeHandler} type="text" name='name' placeholder='Type here'/>
        </div>
        <div className='addproduct-price'>
            <div className='addproduct-itemfield'>
                <p>Price</p>
                <input value={productDetails.old_price} onChange={changeHandler} type="text" name='old_price' placeholder='Type here'/>
            </div>
            <div className='addproduct-itemfield'>
                <p>Offer Price</p>
                <input value={productDetails.new_price} onChange={changeHandler} type="text" name='new_price' placeholder='Type here'/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='addproduct-itemfield'>
            <p>Product Category</p>
            <select value={productDetails.category} onChange={changeHandler} name='category' className='add-product-selector'>
                <option value="women">Women</option>
                <option value="men">Men</option>
                <option value="kids">Kids</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div className='addproduct-itemfield'>
            <label htmlFor='file-input'>
                <img src = {image?URL.createObjectURL(image):upload_area} className='addproduct-thumbnail-img' alt= ""/>
            </label>
            <input onChange={imageHandler} type="file" name='image' id='file-input' hidden/>
        </div>
        <button onClick={()=>{Add_Product()}} className='addproduct-btn'>ADD</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddProduct
```

While executing the code, it is generating the following error:

```
this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
                               ^
ValidationError: Product validation failed: name: Cast to string failed for value "[ 'kids357' ]" (type Array) at path "name", category: Cast to string failed for value "[ 'kids' ]" (type Array) at path "category", new_price: Cast to Number failed for value "[ '65' ]" (type Array) at path "new_price", old_price: Cast to Number failed for value "[ '100' ]" (type Array) at path "old_price"
    at Document.invalidate (C:\Users\rafiz\Documents\Learning\ReactJS\E-Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3201:32)       
    at model.$set (C:\Users\rafiz\Documents\Learning\ReactJS\E-Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1460:12)
    at model.$set (C:\Users\rafiz\Documents\Learning\ReactJS\E-Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1115:16)
    at model.Document (C:\Users\rafiz\Documents\Learning\ReactJS\E-Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:166:12)
    at model.Model (C:\Users\rafiz\Documents\Learning\ReactJS\E-Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:131:12)
    at new model (C:\Users\rafiz\Documents\Learning\ReactJS\E-Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4700:15)
    at C:\Users\rafiz\Documents\Learning\ReactJS\E-Commerce\backend\index.js:87:21
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) 
.
.
.
.
{
        generatedMessage: true,
        code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
        actual: false,
        expected: true,
        operator: '=='
      },
      valueType: 'Array'
    }
  },
  _message: 'Product validation failed'
```

How to resolve this error?

I tried to write code for admin panel of a e-commerce website. It should insert the product information into MongoDB collection.

Comment: Post the code from your front-end where you are making the request. It looks like you are sending it as a series of arrays. Mongoose is telling you it cannot cast these array values to strings or numbers as per your schema.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I am following a video tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y99YgaQjgx4) and writing exactly the same code. For this same code, those values were sent as strings but for me, these are being sent as arrays. I have watched the video again and again to check whether I have made any mistake, but I couldn't find any error and also failed to identify the reason why the values are being sent as arrays.

Comment: I have added the code from front-end where the request is being made. Please help me to identify why the values are being sent as arrays instead of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error you have added, it seems like the payload you have passed is incorrect since all the values are coming into an array format. You have specified string for a name, but the value it received is array. And that goes for all the fields. Do check the `req.body` for the payload received from the client side.

Also a small change in your code.
It seems you're adding 1 to the id field. Instead of going through the array.length, you can use `countDocuments()` to get the count. Optionally, since you're already storing id of the item, you can get the id of the last document added and do `+1` on it.

The `_id` field consists of timestamp, which can be used to fetch the last document.
`1` is used for sorting in **ascending** and `-1` for **descending**.

```
    let product = await Product.find({}).sort({_id: -1});
    let id = product.id + 1
```

[Sorting in Mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#syntax)

[ObjectId in Mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#mongodb-method-ObjectId)

**EDIT**

I checked your code and there is a mistake in the `changeHandler` function. You have to pass value to the key without wrapping it in an array. You just need to pass the key name in array brackets to get the name of the key. Your change should look like this.

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setProductDetails({ ...productDetails, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

[Objects-Square Brackets](https://javascript.info/object#square-brackets)

Comment: Thanks Sandeep M. You are right; the values are being sent as arrays instead of strings but I could not find the reason why the values are being sent as arrays. Actually I am following a video tutorial (youtube.com/watch?v=y99YgaQjgx4) and writing exactly the same code. For this same code, those values were sent as strings but for me, these are being sent as arrays. I have watched the video again and again to check whether I have made any mistake, but I couldn't find any error. That's why, I am posting the code from front end where I am making the request.